# How to call Unix command through pyjamas

Tags: python, pyjamas

I am trying to create web based system using pyjamas and hangs on one functionality.
The functionality is, to click a button and it should run some python programs in back-end. I have to display the logs generated by back-end python program in the same page(where the clicked button is).
I really appreciate your help guys!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tutorial on how to use Pyjamas with AJAX on [this page](http://pyjs.org/book/output/Bookreader.html#Rest%20of%20the%20World) of of Pyjamas book.

Comment: Thanks @farfromhome, i read that article but frankly its not explained in a way it should be. So i googled again, read different articles and what helped me to understand things clearly is [this](http://code.google.com/p/pyjamas/wiki/JSONRpcWithApacheModPython), and [this](http://groups.google.com/group/pyjamas-dev/browse_thread/thread/2ddce43c99c54b57).

Comment: Then, by Stack Overflow custom, you ought to put that in a new answer yourself and select it as the right one, to let people know that you've figured it out by yourself. :)

Comment: Sorry for very very long delayed answer:) 
I had added the solution to my blog 
http://pymantra.pythonblogs.com/90_pymantra/archive/531_pyjamas-run_python_script_onclick_of_button.html